# Is there a way to dynamically name event handlers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Suppose I have a group of buttons, each of which assigns a different color to a clicked element. So, red button makes the clicked element turn red.

```
<div id="color-pickers">
      <button id="red" class="picker"><span class="sr-only">red</span></button>
      <button id="orange" class="picker "><span class="sr-only">orange</span></button>
      <button id="yellow" class="picker"><span class="sr-only">yellow</span></button>
      ...
</div>
```

Rather than write out an event handler for each one, I'd like to write one dynamically named event handler.

So far, I have tried creating an array of color names:

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', ...]
```

then looping through that array:

```
for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  
  // for each color in array, assign it to a button
  colors[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      ...
  });
}
```

Hoping that I would end up with `red.addEventListener...`, `orange.addEventListener...` etc.
But instead, this results in: `TypeError: colors[i].addEventListener is not a function`.

I've tried using template literals without success. [This](https://dev.to/tmikeschu/dynamically-assigning-a-function-name-in-javascript-2d70) seemed promising, but didn't work (possibly because I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on there).

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I can clarify.

*to clarify:*

I'm trying to avoid writing something like:

```
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    doSomething...
});
orange.addEventListener("click", function() {
    doSomething...
});
yellow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    doSomething...
});
```

Instead, I want to write out the list of colors once, then use that list to populate the part that comes before `.addEventListener`. I ended up using the second part of @Titulum's answer, with the list of existing buttons. I might take it a step further and create the buttons programmatically as well, but for now, that does what I want it to. Thanks all.

Comment: You really should have a look at how [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) works

Comment: Are the colors defined on the buttons as id, class, `data-*` attribute, ...? -> Add a [mcve]

Comment: You are try to add event listeners to `string`s, what are you hoping this is going to achieve?

Comment: jQuery has a namespace for the attached events, but the title and the question seem not matching.

Comment: After your last edit you really want to have a look at how `.addEventListener()` works and what "things" you can call it on. Strings won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically create the buttons and/or add an eventlistener like so:

```js
const buttonContainer = document.getElementById('button-container');
const target = document.getElementById('target');

const colors = [ "red", "blue", "yellow" ];

for (const color of colors) {
  const colorButton = document.createElement('button');
  colorButton.innerText = color;
  colorButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
  buttonContainer.appendChild(colorButton);
}
```

```css
#target {

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="button-container"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

You can also add the event listener to an already existing list of buttons, as long as the button identifiers follow a set format:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const colors = [ "red", "blue", "yellow" ];

for (const color of colors) {
  const button = document.getElementById(`button-${color}`);
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-red">red</button>
<button id="button-blue">blue</button>
<button id="button-yellow">yellow</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: _"You can programmatically create the buttons"_ - Why? How do you know that the buttons are not already in the DOM? Why do you think your answer solves OPs problem? Right now OPs question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have updated my answer to also include an already existing list of buttons

Comment: How about waiting for OP to add the relevant and missing information and only then add an answer?

Comment: Why should I? We can do those things at the same time. I only adapted my answer because you asked for a way to make it work with buttons that already exist in the DOM. Because the OP's question does not make any sense does not mean that I can *try* to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you need to integrate your HTML with your JS.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button class="color-button" id="pink">Pink</button>
<button class="color-button" id="yellow">Yellow</button>
<button class="color-button" id="cyan">Cyan</button>

<!-- JS -->
// add EventListener to each .color-button
[].slice(document.getElementsByClassName("color-button")).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler, !1)
});

// use the id-attribute of each button to
// set the button's background colour
const = buttonHandler = (e) => {
    let target = e.target,
        color = target.id;

    target.style.bacgroundColor = color;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to an html element, not to a string.

You need to convert your string to and html element to add an event listner to it.

You can create an object with your nodes and assign click event listners to that.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
const red = document.getElementById("red");
const orange = document.getElementById("orange");
const yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");

const nodeObj = {
    red,
    orange,
    yellow
}

for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    // for each color in array, assign it to a button
    nodeObj[colors[i]].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log(`You clicked ${e.currentTarget.id}`)
    });
}
```

```html
<p id="red">Red</p>
<p id="orange">Orange</p>
<p id="yellow">Yellow</p>
```

OR

You can make use of `eval` for that (This is a dirty fix).

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
const red = document.getElementById("red");
const orange = document.getElementById("orange");
const yellow = document.getElementById("yellow");
for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    // for each color in array, assign it to a button
    eval(colors[i]).addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        console.log(`You clicked ${e.currentTarget.id}`)
    });
}
```

```html
<p id="red">Red</p>
<p id="orange">Orange</p>
<p id="yellow">Yellow</p>
```

Comment: _"Deleting this answer, need to have some better approach other than eval"_ - This is a 1:1 copy of your deleted answer? And we still don't know what OP tries to achieve and how the markup looks like...

Comment: @Andreas Yes its is. But my previous answer also had a different apprach other than eval. Seems like noone had a look into that. So this answer is to highlight that part. Let the other person check the anser. This is the implementation of hat I understood from the question